# Trying to import a CSV file triggers a function which ends up manipulating the data imported into the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Like the question says, I am trying to import a CSV with the following function:

```
def import_users
  path = Rails.root.join('somePath')
  CSV.foreach(path, headers: true) do |row|
    usr = User.new(row.to_hash)
    usr.skip_callbacks = true
    usr.save
  end
  puts "inserts on table users complete"
end
```

As you can tell, it is a simple function.

### Issue:

All the columns with the correct data are imported correctly but in the `User Class` the `password= function (setter)` is triggered:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :skip_callbacks
  validates :password, presence: true, unless: :skip_callbacks

  def password= password
    self[:password] = hash_password password
  end

  private
    
  def hash_password password
     Digest::MD5.hexdigest "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest password}#{salt}"
  end
end
```

> This causes the password column in the database to be rewritten again with **new hashes as passwords** which then prevents login because the column values have changed. The password column in the database does not contain the same info as in the CSV File.

Normally I implemented a `skip_callback` to bypass `password validation` but does not seem to work.

I would really appreciate any kind of help as I have been trying to solve this for a couple of days now and can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to add passwords to database as is without hashing, and validations have nothing to do with it because they will not change the behavior of the `password=` function.
You may patch it with another instance variable like:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :skip_callbacks
  attr_accessor :skip_password_hashing
  validates :password, presence: true, unless: :skip_callbacks

  def password= password
    self[:password] = skip_password_hashing ? password : hash_password(password)
  end

  private
    
  def hash_password password
     Digest::MD5.hexdigest "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest password}#{salt}"
  end
end
```

and then patch import like:

```rb
def import_users
  path = Rails.root.join('somePath')
  CSV.foreach(path, headers: true) do |row|
    usr = User.new(row.to_hash)
    usr.skip_password_hashing = true
    usr.save
  end
  puts "inserts on table users complete"
end
```

I am not sure if it is a good idea to have this possibility in deployed application, but it should work.

Comment: i had to make a tiny change, by changing the -- self[:password] = skip_password_hashing -- to   -- self[:password] = :skip_password_hashing -- a tiny change and it seems to import without creating new hashes!! Thanks this seems to be the correct solution!

Comment: @Najmul I reverted the answer back to version without `:` because using `:` will lead to expression  `:skip_password_hashing ? password : hash_password(password)` being always true.

Comment: this seems to work to some extent. When i remove the colon -- : -- it still triggers the setter when i run the import function from another file. It still ends up creating new hashes, do you have any idea why?